# setting a value in a table JFX

Tags: java, object, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to set a value within a table, I'm currently filling the table with a list of players from my players class, I'm trying to set the score value within the table but struggling. I'm not sure how to set the value within the table. (each player has 10 scores). Any help will be very much appreciated thanks in advance.

Player Class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Player {
    public static final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public int playerID;
    public String name;
    public String scoreString;
    private String preference;
    private String barriers;
    private String[] scores ;
    private int roundtotal;
    private int total ;

public Player(){
    this.playerID = id.incrementAndGet();
    this.name = "";
    this.preference = "Left";
    this.barriers = "Yes";
    this.scores = new String[11] ;
}

public Player( int playerID, String Name, String preference, String barriers) {
    this.playerID = playerID;
    this.name = Name;
    this.preference = preference;
    this.barriers = barriers;
    this.scores = new String[11] ;

}
public int getPlayerID(){ return playerID; }
public void setPlayerID() {this.playerID = playerID;}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String Name) {
    this.name = Name;
}

public String getPreference() {
    return preference;
}

public void setPreference(String preference) {
    this.preference = preference;
}

public String getBarriers() {
    return barriers;
}

public void setBarriers(String barriers) {
    this.barriers = barriers;
}

public void setScore(int turn, int score1, int score2) {
    String scoreString = score1 + "/" + score2;
    System.out.println(scoreString);
    roundtotal = score1 + score2;
    total = total + roundtotal;
    scores[turn] = scoreString;
}
public String getScore(int whichScore) {
    return scores[whichScore] ;
}
public int getTotal() {
    return total ;
}
public String getScoreString(){
    return scoreString;
}
@Override
public String toString () {
    return "Player{" +
            "id='" + playerID + '\'' +
            "Name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", Preference='" + preference + '\'' +
            ", barrires=" + barriers + '\'' +
            ", S1=" + getScore(1) + '\'' +
            ", S2=" + getScore(2) + '\'' +
            ", S3=" + getScore(3) + '\'' +
            ", S4=" + getScore(4) + '\'' +
            ", S5=" + getScore(5) + '\'' +
            ", S6=" + getScore(6) + '\'' +
            ", S7=" + getScore(7) + '\'' +
            ", S8=" + getScore(8) + '\'' +
            ", S9=" + getScore(9) + '\'' +
            ", S10=" + getScore(10) + '\'' +
            ", Total =" + total +
            '}';
}
}
```

Table FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="scoreboard" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
          <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="nameCol" prefWidth="150.0" resizable="false" text="Player Name">
              <cellValueFactory>
                  <PropertyValueFactory property="name" />
              </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn fx:id="scores1col" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="1">
              <cellValueFactory>
                  <PropertyValueFactory property="scores1col" />
              </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="score2col" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="2">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="score2col" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="s3" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="3">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="getScore(3)" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="s4" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="4">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="getScore(4)" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="s5" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="5">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="getScore(5)" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="s6" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="6">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="getScore(6)" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="s7" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="7">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="getScore(7)" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="s8" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="8">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="getScore(8)" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="s9" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="9">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="getScore(9)" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="s10" prefWidth="70.0" resizable="false" text="10">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="getScore(10)" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="totalCol" prefWidth="85.0" resizable="false" text="Total">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="total" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
              </TableColumn>
          </columns>
           <GridPane.margin>
              <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
           </GridPane.margin>
        </TableView>
```

Comment: why not working with the controller class ?

Comment: I am using a controller class, would I be able to update the value through there?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`PropertyValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html): fairly obviously, the strings you are providing as the property name will not work. You need to implement the cell value factories yourself, in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you can (assuming the column is defined with the correct type) do

```
scores1col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getScore(0)));
```

and similarly for the other columns.

Comment: What do you mean by defined as the correct type? (Withing the FXML document) ?

Comment: @MorganChorlton No, in the controller. Should be `TableColumn<Player, Number>`.

Comment: Where would the best place to place these be? I have created a class that has them all in is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @MorganChorlton I don't understand the question. The code I posted goes in the controller, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Oh yeh sorry, this works now thanks for your help, :)